# Issue with creating additional contact forms - recaptcha

Tags: php, forms, recaptcha, contact-form, magento-1.6

I'm trying to create an additional contact form and am running into an issue - initially I modified the default contacts form but ran into issues so tried just using the default contact form on a CMS page, using the following code:

```
{{block type='core/template' template='contacts/form.phtml'}}
```

but whenever I try to submit the form it produces the following error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setFormAction() on a non-object in /home/urider/web/app/code/community/Fontis/Recaptcha/controllers/ContactsController.php on line 32
```

line 31,32 is as follows:

```
$this->loadLayout();
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('contactForm')->setFormAction( Mage::getUrl('*/*/post') );
```

From what I've seen online it may be something to do with the layout not being loaded but I'm really not sure, any thoughts?